# Programmatically set association data for three-state workflow instance (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

I want to programmatically set association data for three-state workflow instance.
I want to do this using a feature receiver (on activate), using C# code through visual studio.

Is this possible ? Any code sample ?

Comment: Good question. Ever found a way to do this?